# LATEX не хочет отображать брать даннные из буфера

Tags: c++, windows, latex

Работаю с такой программой **latex2rtf-2.3.1_win-NO-GUI**, сформировал текст и задал создать текст в .РТФ формате файл.
Он мне пишет ошибку в `cmd`.

Вот её вывожу:

> Error! Could not find <\end {tabular}> 
>   in 16000 characters
>   Recompile with larger BUFFSIZE in getTexUntil() in parser.c

`\end {tabular}` есть просто, но находится дальше первых 16000 знаков.

Пытался найти как расширить буфер в документации программы но там этого нет.
Теперь думаю что это виндовский файл `parser.c` где мне его найти и как поправить если я прав в своих домыслах?

Comment: в [исходниках](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: По сути, вам предлагают скомпилировать `latex2rtf` самостоятельно, подкрутив параметры в исходном коде.

Comment: в версии 2.3.16, кстати, buffsize уже и так увеличен до 20000. отчего бы не заменить скомпилированную пять лет назад версию [на более новую](https://sourceforge.net/projects/latex2rtf/files/latex2rtf-win/2.3.16/)? ну, если нет желания самому [пересобрать из исходников](https://sourceforge.net/projects/latex2rtf/files/latex2rtf-unix/2.3.16/).